# Replacing if else with OO aproach

Tags: java, oop, if-statement

Lets say I have:

```
if (count <= instance.getFCount()) {
    //do something and return String
} else if (count <= instance.getFSCount()) {
    //do something and return String
} else if (count <= instance.getTCount()) {
    //do something and return String
} else if (count <= instance.getOCount()) {
    //do something and return String
}
```

I am thinking how can I replace this code into something more object oriented. The problem is that if I would have statement like this:

```
if (count <= 0) {
    //do something and return String
} else if (count <= 1) {
    //do something and return String
} else if (count <= 2) {
    //do something and return String
} else if (count <= 3) {
    //do something and return String
}
```

I could replace it with some factory pattern or enum based approach because my values 0, 1, 2, 3 would always be static. For e.g. I would create a map to hold the class against the number, then if my count is 0 I would know that I need to create an instance from the class which was mapped with zero and so on.

But now I am thinking if there is any way to be done if I don't have the static values in if condition, because for e.g. what is returned to this: `instance.getOCount()` might be different depending on the configuration.

Could you give me some thoughts how to achieve this?

Comment: Polymorphism was born to eliminate switch and if/else chains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think using patterns is the solution here...everything will be harder to read than your original code. But if you are sure, this is one option:
Lets say your instance belongs to a class User. Create an interface

```
public interface IDynamicAction<T> {
boolean select(T t);
String action(T t);
}
```

Make a list

```
List<IDynamicAction<User>> actions = new ArrayList<IDynamicAction<User>>();
actions.add(new IDynamicAction<User>() {
@Override
public boolean select(User instance) {
    return count <= instance.getFSCount();
}

@Override
public String action(User t) {
    System.out.println("count <= instance.getFSCount()");
    return "count <= instance.getFSCount()";
}
});


actions.add(new IDynamicAction<User>() {
@Override
public boolean select(User instance) {
    return count <= instance.getTCount();
}
@Override
public String action(User t) {
    System.out.println("count <= instance.getTCount()");
    return " count <= instance.getTCount()";
}
});

actions.add(new IDynamicAction<User>() {
@Override
public boolean select(User instance) {
    return count <= instance.getOCount();
}
@Override
public String action(User t) {
    System.out.println("count <= instance.getOCount()");
    return " count <= instance.getOCount()";
}
});
```

And execute your code with

```
for(IDynamicAction<User> action : actions){
if(action.select(instance)){
    String s = action.action(instance);
    System.out.println(s);
    break;
}
```

}

Notice the break, I'm assuming based in your code only one action can execute
If you don't need a return value you may use an abstract class instead of an interface and make the if(select) action(); a part of the AbstractDynamicAction class the code will be nicer

Java7 does not really help doing that kind of stuff. Closures would make this things easier on the eye...but IMHO, your original multiple IF is the way to go.

Answer (score 11):

When you have lots of different `if else` statements, you can employ a [Strategy Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern). This helps you create manageable code that conforms to the best practice.

Comment: How is it going to help with a chain of `if`s that are *not* based on checking the instance???

Comment: @dasblinkenlight - exactly, thanks. Chris Cooney - Have you even read my question until the end? I could use strategy pattern in the second example which I gave. How can I use this if behind the if condition operator is the value which is not always the same?

Comment: Remember to mark the correct answer for future readers. In this instance though, there is no ONE correct answer. It's data modelling and design; rather than mathematical development. :)

Comment: this is a old answer, but the right Design Pattern for the right problem = a timeless solution.  Just the pattern I was looking for thank you.

Answer (score 5):

I believe there's no need to replace such a simple logic with a design pattern, it's not justified. A `switch` would be an improvement (assuming `count` is an integer), but why create a bunch of classes? it'd be justified only if each one had additional, different behavior.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik the states that currently the values are static, for that a `switch` might work (we don't know if count is an integer). For the "what-if" scenario of dynamic values, you're right.

Answer (score 3):

If you use a `NavigableMap` such as a `TreeMap`, the keys being your thresholds and values being `Callable`s, you'll be able to retrieve the appropriate `Callable` and invoke it, all in a one-liner. The relevant method is `NavigableMap#ceilingEntry`.

```
final NavigableMap<Integer, Callable<String>> strats = new TreeMap<>();

...

return strats.ceilingEntry(val).getValue().call(args);
```